# getResourceModel can't find local collection

Tags: resource-model

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customreports/report_collection');
```

where customreports is my module name and I have a Collection.php file within Model/Resource/Report folder.  getResourceModel is returning false or NULL or whatever.

I basically copied Collection.php from Mage's Reports/Model/Resource/Report/ folder but removed some functions.

Why would getResourceModel return NULL?

Comment: Add your config.xml here

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2398610

Comment: What is mean of using one node (<resourceModel>) multiple times? See config.xml documentation references to right direction.

Comment: Your config is broken. the ```<resourceModel>``` node does not contain a resource model class name, but the resource model class group. Also, you can only have a single node with any given name, so your final ```<resourceModel>``` node value will override the previous ones. Check the gist linked from my answer for further information.

Comment: ok, but what I've been doing has worked for other collections.  I have several custom reports each with their own collection.  Can you give a quick example of how I should do that for like 2 of them?

Comment: actually, I think my config.xml appears to work now.

Comment: Nope :(        I got mixed up with reports

Answer (score 2):

The collection needs to be initialized in the constructor:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('customreports/report');
}
```

The string `customreports/report` is then used for the collections model (`Mage::getModel('customreports/report')`) and also, to instantiate the resource model (`Mage::getResourceModel('customreports/report')`) when needed.

If you are initializing the collection correctly, follow the steps [listed in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Vinai/5466424) regarding resource model instantiation to find the bug.

Comment: well when I do $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/report_collection'); it works

Comment: Instantiation might work, but loading (```$collection->load()```) will not unless the mapping to the resource model is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can your sure renamed the class name as {Namespace}_{Module}_Model_Resource_Report_Collection.
And your config xml like this:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <your_module>
            <class>{Namespace}_{Module}_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>your_module_resource</resourceModel>
        </your_module>
        <your_module_resource>
            <class>{Namespace}_{Module}_Model_Resource</class>
        </your_module_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Ok, I was missing that but when I fix it, it still doest work.  You want me to pastebin that section to see if it's right?

Comment: Yeas sir, if still issue list your config.xml

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2398610

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely It can't find the collection because the file does not exist. Check if you have physically a file:
{Namespace}/{Module}/Model/Resource/Report/Collection.php

And inside it, something like that:

```
class Magentotutorial_Complexworld_Model_Resource_Eavblogpost_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customreports/report');
    }
}
```